Adding by Color Fill
I am trying to write a VBA Code that allows me to sum up values in a cell that have matching fill colors. The problem is I have some cells that have text and I need those to be skipped.
Function People(SumRange As Range, SumColor As Range)
    Dim SumColorValue As Integer
    Dim TotalSum As Long
    SumColorValue = SumColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    Set rCell = SumRange
    For Each rCell In SumRange
    If rCell.IsText(rCell.Value) =  Then
    TotalSum = TotalSum + 0
    ElseIf rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = SumColorValue Then
    TotalSum = TotalSum + rCell.Value
    End If
    Next rCell
    People = TotalSum
End Function

This is what I currently have and I keep getting an error withing the cell being #Name!

#Name error means you most likely have this in the worksheet or ThisWorkbook module and not a general module attached to the workbook.

or it is being called wrong.  Please show an example of the function call.

Why do you have Set rCell = SumRange?

If rCell.IsText(rCell.Value) =  Then this line will not run - a Range object doesn't have an IsText method.   Call your function from a Sub so you can debug it, before trying it out in a worksheet cell.

Modify your code as below:
Function People(SumRange As Range, SumColor As Range)
    Dim SumColorValue As Integer
    Dim TotalSum As Long
    SumColorValue = SumColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In SumRange
    If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) Then
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = SumColorValue Then
            TotalSum = TotalSum + rCell.Value
        End If
    End If
    Next rCell
    People = TotalSum
End Function

If an error still exists it's source is elsewhere.
